# Release date for iOS 11?

Tags: ios

Currently iOS 11 is in "*preview mode*" and only available to developers & beta testers. I've Googled high and low and cannot seem to find a firm/reliable date for when it will go "public"/GA.

**Anyone have any insider knowledge here?**

Comment: Asking when Apple will do X is off topic for the main site. The [chat] would be the best place for speculation and [meta] is the place for official announcements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apple will officially announce the release date at its *Lets meet at our place* event.

**This event will be held at 10am on Tuesday 12 September 2017 (Pacific Time).**

No-one here can give you a 100% certain date, except to say it'll be within a short period of the announcement. Almost certainly this month.

Comment: You are probably right.  Sometimes, however, products only appear months after the announcement.  But I still expect a release date will be announced on the 12th.  Either to coincide with the availability of the new iPhones, or shortly before.

Comment: @Monomeeth (or really, anybody): Do you know if it has been announced yet?! I can't seem to find a link to the event's livestream.

Comment: Ah nm found it **September 19th, 2017** was the correct answer!